# Get element id during onScroll in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm facing a problem.

I need to get the id of the div witch is on top on my page.

How can I get when the div items is scrolled I can get the id of the div witch is the most visible on top ?

Actually, with this code it works but because there's some margin/padding between box, it creates a bug by echoing `undefined` or the first `id`.

Anyone to help please with this ?

---

## My HTML:

```
<div class="items"> <!-- Scrollable -->
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="item1">...</div> <!-- A lot of text -->
        <div id="item2">...</div> <!-- A lot of text -->
        <div id="item3">...</div> <!-- A lot of text -->
        <div id="item4">...</div> <!-- A lot of text -->
     </div>
</div>
```

## My JS:

```
jQuery('.items').scroll(function() {
    var c = $(this).children('.content').children();
    var top = c.first();
    c.each(function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset().top;
        if(offset < 0 && offset >= -$(this).height()){
            top = $(this);
            return false;
        }
    });

    var name = top.attr('id');
    console.log(name);
});
```

---

Code in action in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7n9cswxt/1/). In it you will see that when the scroll arrived between two coloured div with padding, `item1` will be echoed. I would like to keep the current one.

Comment: Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/7n9cswxt/2/ (added margin)

Comment: @nevermind: a little bit. I took your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `outerHeight` instead of height. this includes all padding and margin:

```
$(this).outerHeight(true)
```